# Python nested dictionary gets overwritten even after keeping a copy

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary to look up some information . Because of python's way of tagging data , i have created copies of the dicts using the `copy` method of dict . But when I update the innermost dict , it changes other dicts of all other days (mon to fri) .

Here's how I initailize my main dictionary : **self.faculty_to_day_hour_slot_map**

```
self.faculty_to_day_hour_slot_map = {}
day_to_hour = {}
faculty_to_data = {} 

hour_to_allotflag = {}
for hour in range(1 , 9):
    hour_to_allotflag.update({hour : {'alloted': False}.copy()}.copy()) ;

for day in ['mon' , 'tue' , 'wed' , 'thu' , 'fri' , 'sat']:
    day_to_hour.update({day : hour_to_allotflag.copy()}.copy()) ;

for faculty_object in self.faculties:
    self.faculty_to_day_hour_slot_map.update({faculty_object.id : day_to_hour.copy()}.copy()) ;
```

The problem occurs when I update the innermost dict like this :

```
self.faculty_to_day_hour_slot_map.get(faculty).get(day).get(hour)['alloted'] = True
```

For example :

```
self.faculty_to_day_hour_slot_map.get('uniqueid').get('mon').get(1)['alloted'] = True
```

This makes all the 'alloted' as True inside each day ( mon to fri) with hour = 1

How to fix this problem ? why is this occuring despite using `copy` method ?

The original dictionary looks like this :

```
{51: {'mon': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'tue': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'wed': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'thu': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'fri': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'sat': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}}},
 15: {'mon': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'tue': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'wed': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'thu': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'fri': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'sat': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}}},
 16: {'mon': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'tue': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'wed': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'thu': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'fri': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'sat': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}}},
 17: {'mon': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'tue': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'wed': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'thu': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'fri': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'sat': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}}},
 18: {'mon': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'tue': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'wed': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'thu': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'fri': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'sat': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}}},
 19: {'mon': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'tue': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'wed': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'thu': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'fri': {1: {'alloted': True},
   2: {'alloted': True},
   3: {'alloted': True},
   4: {'alloted': True},
   5: {'alloted': True},
   6: {'alloted': True},
   7: {'alloted': True},
   8: {'alloted': True}},
  'sat': {1: {'alloted': True},
..... and so on
```

Comment: try `deepcopy`.

Comment: Use `copy.deepcopy` in the `copy` module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copy() function creates a shallow copy of the object. What you might need here is a deep copy.

```
import copy
d1 = {"Strongest Avenger": "Thor"}
d2 = copy.deepcopy(d1)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by the comments and the previous answer, you should use deepcopy. Also, in the interest of readability, you can use `functools.reduce` to create the nested `dict`.

```
from functools import reduce
from copy import deepcopy

faculty = list(range(10))
days = ['mon' , 'tue' , 'wed' , 'thu' , 'fri' , 'sat']
hours = list(range(1, 9))

res = reduce(
        lambda d, ks: {k: deepcopy(d) for k in ks},
        [hours, days, faculty],
        {'alloted': True}
        )
```